# Swift - Can not detect button action in uitableviewcell after set auto layout

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

There is a button in my custom tableviewCell, when I press the UIButton, it will open another view in my app.

Everything is okay after I try to active the auto layout attribute.
And even I don't set any constraint to my button, it still can not be 
detected and shift to another view.

[A snapshot image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pxo86.png)

Can anyone help me ?

UPDATE:
Thanks for Korpel, rose and Tobonaut.
Yes I had create the segue on the button to another view, and it worked before I set the attribute of autoLayout. I was sure I added the segue and identifier both on the storyboard and the code .

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier=="RemindSegue" {
        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! RemindTimeController   
        let senderButton = sender as? UIButton
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: (senderButton?.tag)!, inSection: 1)
        destination.delegate = self

    }
}
```

After I set the autoLayout option, I could only click on my custom tableCell, which was dynamically created on the runtime. And the click on the button didn't work anymore.

The button's still there, there was no constraint added to it.

Comment: have you created a segue?Or the problem is the autolayout?Because those 2 are completely different meanings

Comment: would you post some code? it's not quite clear.

Comment: Does the click not work, do you use a thread dispatcher and the view is just waiting? A code snippet would help a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I find the answer of it.
I added the following code in my custom tableViewCell when initiate...
which disabled my button to use.
But I don't really understand the reason behind it...

```
self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```